# Exterior differentiation of foliations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, foliations, derham-cohomology

Let $M$ be  a  differentiable manifold.

Let  $T^*M$  be  the  cotangent bundle  of  $M$.

Consider  the  exterior differentiation  $d:  A^p(M)\longrightarrow  A^{p+1}(M)$,  where $A^p(M)=\Gamma(\bigwedge^p T^*M)$,  $p=0,1,2,\dotsc$.

Let  $L$  be  a  subbundle  of  $T^*M$.

Suppose $L$  is  a  foliation,  i.e.  for any sections $X,Y\in \Gamma(L)$, we  have  $[X,Y]\in \Gamma(L)$.

***Question.***

Whether or  not  could  we  have  a  well-defined   exterior differentiation  $d:  \Gamma(\bigwedge^pL)\longrightarrow  \Gamma(\bigwedge^{p+1}L)$?

Answer (score 10):

I think you might be confusing $L\subset T^*M$ with $L^\perp\subset TM$, since you can't compute the Lie bracket of sections of $L$, which are $1$-forms.

The condition that $L$ define a foliation is that for any two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ that are sections of $L^\perp$, we have that $[X,Y]$ is also a section of $L^\perp$.  In this case, there is, indeed, a well-defined first-order operator $$\bar d: \Gamma(\Lambda^p(T^*/L))\to  \Gamma(\Lambda^{p+1}(T^*/L)),$$ that is, in a very real sense, a quotient of the usual exterior differential operator.

Comment: It is interesting to observe that the integrable sub-bundle $L^\perp\subset TM$ could be replaced by any Lie algebroid $\mathfrak{g}\to TM$. There is then still a well-defined square zero operator $\Gamma(\wedge^p\mathfrak{g})\to  \Gamma(\wedge^{p+1}\mathfrak{g})$.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that in your question, you meant that  is a subbundle of the tangent bundle  rather than the cotangent bundle ∗. If so, the answer is yes; this is a classical tool in the theory of foliations, called the "tangential" or "leafwise" exterior differential; see e.g. this post [Leafwise de Rham cohomology (A true definition of differential forms along leaves)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/333221/105095). If you maintain the cotangent bundle, then Robert's observation is of course right.

Comment: How does this square with @RobertBryant's [observation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/444391) that the problem is probably misstated?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444386/exterior-differentiation-of-foliations/452311#comment1170019_452311), it's @ShiquanRen's question, not mine.  But thanks for clarifying!